# How to reset password in User Management System in Asp net mvc

Tags: user-management, reset-password, asp-net-mvc-1

Can anyone help me to make Forgot Password in User Management system to reset the password with sending link on email.

Thanks

Comment: What version of asp.net are u using? razor engine? What have you tried. Have you looked for tutorials? This question is a bit to broad, try some things and come back with your errors then we can help. We are not here to do your (home)work.

Comment: http://www.asp.net/identity/overview/features-api/account-confirmation-and-password-recovery-with-aspnet-identity This is anoverview of how mvc identity works. Try following this guide